# How to fetch data from aspnet_membership and aspnet_users table using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to fetch email and username from aspnet_membership and aspnet_users table respectively. 
I am using join query in SqlDataAdapter to fetch the data from both the table but it is not returning any record. If I use SQL server management studio same query returns the records but not in application.

I have merged the aspnetdb tables with my OnlineLibrary Database using aspnet_regsql.exe tool.

```
public partial class PagesUser_WelcomeUser : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   string name;
   string mail;
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=Rahul-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=OnlineLibrary");
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    name = Page.User.Identity.Name;
    SqlDataAdapter adpmail = new SqlDataAdapter("Select UserName, Email  from aspnet_Membership M join aspnet_Users U on M.UserId=U.UserId where U.username='" + name + "'", conn);
    DataSet dsmail = new DataSet();


    adpmail.Fill(dsmail, "Library_User");
    mail = dsmail.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
    txtMail.Text = mail;
}
```

Kindly let me know what is missing.

Comment: with same parameter value `name` ?

Comment: You could save yourself some trouble by simply getting the `MembershipUser` and reading its email property: `MembershipUser u = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);`